# Camera inside fragment activity

Tags: android, fragment

I am trying to click an image from camera inside the fragment but the startactivityforresult is not calling inside that fragment but it redirects to main fragmentactivity , I have tried a lot of examples but i didn't get success, please give me a sample for that.

Comment: What have you done so far?

Comment: i have code for camera but when the camera returns data intent to startactivityforresult it redirects to mainfragment to solve this i have tried many examples which uses fragment replacement code inside mainfragment but no luck

Comment: Follow this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25848803/using-camera-inside-an-app-using-surfaceview-in-android

Answer (score 0):

You should check [this github repo](https://github.com/rexstjohn/UltimateAndroidCameraGuide/blob/master/camera/src/main/java/com/ultimate/camera/fragments/NativeCameraFragment.java). It contain a simple example of Camera preview inside a fragment.

Comment: So you have to import this whole project into your existing project?

Comment: No, you can import only the camera fragment class and adapte it to your need, it has pratically no depencies.